# Fortify complaints about LDAP entry poisoning

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

In my project, I am using below code for the authentication using LDAP, In my WeBSecurityContext

```
 authenticationMngrBuilder.ldapAuthentication().userDetailsContextMapper(getLdapUser())
            .contextSource(ldapContext())
            .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)))");
```

Here "authenticationMngrBuilder"is of type org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder

"LDAP Entry Poisoning
An application that performs an object-returning LDAP search will allow attackers to control the LDAP response to run arbitrary code on the server."

Fortify scan complaints that this is vulnerable because it returns LDAP response as Java object.

Any other alternative for this?

Comment: https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Security-Research-Blog/Introducing-JNDI-Injection-and-LDAP-Entry-Poisoning/ba-p/219821 and https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Munoz-A-Journey-From-JNDI-LDAP-Manipulation-To-RCE-wp.pdf  provide more detail about LDAP Entry Poisoning

Comment: @ANP How did u solve this problem?